# Prove each of these statements from each other $\exists x, y: ax +by = 1$ and $\exists u,v: au = bv + 1 $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, divisibility, proof-explanation, gcd-and-lcm

Hello I am trying to prove the following:

We have show that two numbers a and b are relatively prime if and only if some integer linear combination of them equals 1, that is, if:
 $$\exists x, y: ax +by = 1$$ 
where x and y range over the integers,

and $$\exists u,v: au = bv + 1 $$

where u and v range over the naturals. Prove each of these two statements from each other.

How would I go about this? I decided that I would start by trying to prove the second statement from the first. I started off by instantiating two variables in the first statement for some integer f and g and isolating the ax term:

$$ ∃x,y:ax+by=1 $$
$$ a(f) + b(g) = 1 \space for \space integers \space f \space and \space g $$

$$ a(f) = 1 - b(g)$$

I do not know how to continue on after this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an exercise in elementary transformations, and possibly working backward.

Suppose $x,y$ are such that $ax+by = 1$.

Without loss of generality, we assume that $y$ is negative (otherwise, we can make it so, since $a(x+nb) +b(y-na) = 1 $ for all natural numbers $n$, so just choose $n$ large enough and put $x := x +nb$ and $y := y - na$), in which case $x$ is positive (leaving out trivial cases).

Let $u = x , v= - y$. Then, $ax + by = au-bv = 1 \implies au = bv+1$.

Similarly, if $au=bv+1$, then putting $x=u$ and $y=-v$ gives $ax+by=1$ for some integers $x,y$ (here, $y$ will be negative).

---

EDIT :

For the first part, we have to assume that there exist integers $x,y$ such that $ax+by = 1$. From this, we have to show the existence of $u,v$ natural numbers such that $au = bv+1$.

So we have assumed that $x,y$ exist. I want to now ensure, that $y$ is negative. How do I do this? Let us take an example to clarify.

Let $a=5, b=3$. You can check for yourself, that with $x=-1, y=2$, we get that $ax+by = -5 + 6 = 1$. How do I ensure that $y$ is negative? Here's how:

Let $n$ be any fixed natural number (what it is, we shall decide later). Note that:
$$
1 = (ax + by) = (ax + anb) + (by - anb) = a(x+nb) + b(y-na) 
$$

The crux of this transformation is the following:

> *Given* **one** *pair of numbers $x,y$ satisfying $ax+by=1$, we can generate* **infinitely** *many pairs of numbers $c=x+nb,d=y-na$ such that $ac+bd=1$, since the parameter $n$ can vary over all natural numbers*.

In our case, $a=5,b=3$, so we can write:
$$
1 = 5(-1+3n) + 3(2-5n)
$$

Suppose we put $n=1$, then we get $1 = 5(2) + 3(-3)$. If we write this as $ax+by=1$, then we see that $x$ is positive, *and $y$ is negative*.

From here, everything I have said should work out.

Please clarify if doubts persist.

Comment: The negative sign is confusing me. Can we set $ v = -y $ even though v needs to be a natural in what we are trying to prove? Naturals can't be negative so how can we do this?

Comment: @BobFlanders Because you want $v$ to be a natural number, one cannot automatically set $v=-y$, since then $v$ would be negative if $y$ were positive. However, what I am doing is *forcing* $y$ to be negative, by adjusting it's value using the parameter $n$. Once that is done, setting $v=-y$ will give $v$ as a natural number, rather than just an integer.

Comment: Can you explain this: a(x+nb)+b(y−na)=1in a bit more detail? I understand what you are doing now, but do not know where the +nb and -na terms derive from.

Comment: Ok, I shall edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes perfect sense now.

Comment: You are welcome. Also, I am very happy with your question, so $+1$ on my part.